# Component with TStrings property has "Code Editor" disabled in String List Editor

Tags: delphi

I have written a Delphi component that has a property of type TStrings. All works well except that when the String List Editor is launched, the "Code Editor" button is disabled. Anyone know what I need to set to allow this?

Perhaps this is due to being called from the collection editor?

The entire component is is about 80 lines so I put it all here. It is a VCL component.

```
// Simple example of of creating a OwnedCollection of TStrings
unit TextStorageMin;

interface

uses
   System.Classes, System.SysUtils, Winapi.Windows, System.Generics.Collections;

type

// Storage class to store TStrings
  TStorageStrings = class(TCollectionItem)
  private
    FStrings: TStrings;
    procedure SetStrings(const Value: TStrings);
  public
  published
    constructor Create(Collection: TCollection); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    // Why, when this is brought up in the Strings List Editor, is
    // the "Code Editor" not enabled.
    property Strings: TStrings read FStrings write SetStrings;
  end;

  // Just simple Owned Collection
  TStorageList = class(TOwnedCollection);

  // This our component.
  TTextStorageMin = class(TComponent)
  private
    FStorageList: TStorageList;
  public
  published
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Items: TStorageList read FStorageList write FStorageList;
  end;

  procedure Register;

implementation

// Register it
procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('CompDev', [TTextStorageMin]);
end;

{ TTextStorage }

constructor TTextStorageMin.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FStorageList := TStorageList.Create(AOwner, TStorageStrings);
end;

destructor TTextStorageMin.Destroy;
begin
  FStorageList.Free;
  inherited;
end;

{ TStorageStrings }

constructor TStorageStrings.Create(Collection: TCollection);
begin
  inherited;
  FStrings := TStringList.Create;
end;

destructor TStorageStrings.Destroy;
begin
  FStrings.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TStorageStrings.SetStrings(const Value: TStrings);
begin
  FStrings.Assign(Value);
end;
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of code in the form of a [mre]  that demonstrates this issue?

Comment: What do you mean with "Code Editor button"? It does not seem to be a part of your code. So, what is it?

Comment: @TomBrunberg: The OP is almost certainly referring to the "Code Editor..." button in [the `TStrings` design-time editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbcl6.png). (It's the button that caused a large number of RAD Studio IDE bug reports recently, because it generated an AV when clicked.)

Comment: Ah, ok @Andreas that makes sense. Must confess, I never noticed that button although I often use the list editor for Q.A.D. tests.

Answer (score 0):

Your main component is coded all wrong. It is completely mismanaging the ownership of the `TStorageList` object.  It is assigning the wrong `Owner` to the object, and there is no property setter implementee to avoid a memory leak and taking ownership of an external object (in this case, one created and destroyed by the IDE at design-time).

Also, your `TStorageStrings` class is missing an overload of `Assign()` (or `AssignTo()`), which also plays into the above mismanagement.

The code should look more like this instead:

```pascal
// Simple example of of creating a OwnedCollection of TStrings
unit TextStorageMin;

interface

uses
  System.Classes;

type
  // Storage class to store TStrings
  TStorageStrings = class(TCollectionItem)
  private
    FStrings: TStrings;
    procedure SetStrings(const Value: TStrings);
  public
    constructor Create(Collection: TCollection); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Assign(ASource: TPersistent); override;
  published
    property Strings: TStrings read FStrings write SetStrings;
  end;

  // Just simple Owned Collection
  TStorageList = class(TOwnedCollection);

  // This our component.
  TTextStorageMin = class(TComponent)
  private
    FStorageList: TStorageList;
    procedure SetItems(const Value: TStorageList);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Items: TStorageList read FStorageList write SetItems;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

// Register it
procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('CompDev', [TTextStorageMin]);
end;

{ TTextStorage }

constructor TTextStorageMin.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FStorageList := TStorageList.Create(Self, TStorageStrings);
end;

destructor TTextStorageMin.Destroy;
begin
  FStorageList.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TTextStorageMin.SetItems(const Value: TStorageList);
begin
  FStorageList.Assign(Value);
end;

{ TStorageStrings }

constructor TStorageStrings.Create(Collection: TCollection);
begin
  inherited Create(Collection);
  FStrings := TStringList.Create;
end;

destructor TStorageStrings.Destroy;
begin
  FStrings.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TStorageStrings.Assign(ASource: TPersistent);
begin
  if ASource is TStorageStrings then
    FStrings.Assign(TStorageStrings(ASource).Strings)
  else
    inherited;
end;

procedure TStorageStrings.SetStrings(const Value: TStrings);
begin
  FStrings.Assign(Value);
end;

end.
```

Comment: While I agree that it is a bug, it does not seem to fix the issue.

Comment: @BillF bad things happen in the IDE  when you break the chain of ownership. But with proper ownership, I've never had a problem with nested collections (several levels deep), TStrings properties inside of collections, etc.

Comment: If I create a property directly, not part of an owned collection, it works as expected. This only seems to be an issue with part of a collection.

Comment: @BillF like I've said, I've written TStrings properties inside of collections, so I know it works when used properly. That being said, I just noticed another bug in your code. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I'll have to look more careful at your code..(later) but I tried it and it still has the same problem, the "Code Editor..." button is still disabled.

Comment: @BillF what “code editor button” are you referring to exactly? And which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Surely the OP is referring to [the string list editor's button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbcl6.png)?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes "that" button.